# What is the Objective-C equivalent of Array.lastIndexOf(element, fromIndex)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, lastindexof

I come from a JavaScript/ActionScript background and am used to doing `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` on strings and arrays. For `NSString`s, both of these were relatively simple:

```
// equivalent of JavaScript's string.indexOf(substring, fromIndex)
[string rangeOfString:substring
              options:nil
                range:NSMakeRange(fromIndex, string.length - fromIndex)].location;

// equivalent of JavaScript's string.lastIndexOf(substring, fromIndex)
[string rangeOfString:substring 
              options:NSBackwardsSearch 
                range:NSMakeRange(string.length - fromIndex, fromIndex)].location;
```

For `NSArray`s, I managed to figure out `indexOf`, but couldn't find a native function to do `lastIndexOf`:

```
// equivalent of JavaScript's array.indexOf(item, fromIndex)
[array indexOfObject:item 
             inRange:NSMakeRange(fromIndex, array.count - fromIndex)];
```

What would be the code to find the `lastIndexOf` an element in an array within a range? Will it require more than a single selector call?

Comment: will you feel happy to use more than one method/sentences ?

Comment: I would be okay with more than one method/sentences. And no, this is not a duplicate, because I am looking for something that also considers the second parameter `fromIndex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a single method call to `-[NSArray indexOfObjectWithOptions:passingTest:]`, though it requires passing a block.

```
[array indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx < fromIndex) *stop = YES;
    return [obj isEqual:item];
}];
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I was trying to figure out how to check for index using this selector, without success. Setting `*stop` does the trick!